# Effective number of samples in a correlated dataset

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I would like to estimate the number of effective samples in a time seris, that we can suppose to be stationary. Here for example https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/autocorr/ they suggest to use:

$$\alpha=1+2\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\rho_i$$

Then $N_{eff}=N/\alpha$.

I did some calculation and I thought to justify this in the following way. If use suppose that $X_1,..X_n$ are identically distributed (with zero mean to make things simple) but with a correlation $E[X_iX_j]=f(|i-j|)$, than calling $M=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i}{N}$ the sample mean we have the identity:

$$\sigma^2(M)=\sigma^2/(N/\alpha)$$

with

$$\alpha=1+2\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\rho_i\left(\frac{N-i}{N}\right)$$

letting $N$ become large I think we should have a justification of our formula.

My question is:

- QUESTION 1: There is no reason that the formula should respect $\alpha\ge1$. Actually $\alpha$ can also be zero. Does the formula makes sense in such a case? Does this mean that this approach is of limited usage and makes sense only for the sample mean?
- QUESTION 2: Would it make more sense to use as a definition: $$\alpha=1+2\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\rho^2_i$$, or
  $$\alpha=1+2\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}|\rho_i|$$
  ?

As a further question, that if prompted by the community I can do separately, to apply any of these formulas it would be very useful to estimate a cutoff where the autocorrelation has gone to zero. I read that such a test statistics for lag $i$ should be:

$$t=\frac{\rho_i}{\sqrt{(1 - \rho_i^2) / (N - i - 1)}}$$

and that should be distributed as a t student with $N-i-1$ degrees of freedom under the null hypothesis.

- QUESTION 3: were can I find a reference for the derivation of the formula above and check when it applies (e.g. does it have normality assumptions)